# Internet is not running on Virtual machine

Tags: macos, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using using virtual box on windows 10, my guest machine is Mac OS X El Capitan. Host machine(Windows 10) is connected to wi-fi, but no internet on guest machine. I tried every solution available on internet. I have already killed 2 days on this.

Any help here please?

This is my host machine ipconfig
[image]

This is my virtual box settings
[image]

below is my guest machine ifconfig
[image]

Comment: What settings you have configured for virtual machine.

Comment: @vembutech I tried using NAT, BRIDGE Adapter

Comment: can you post the ipconfig of the windows 10 machine, and the ifconfig (or equivilent) on the MAC, and state what networking mode is currently in/ (NAT, BRIDGE etc)

Comment: @StevenDavison I have updated my question, please take a look into it.

Comment: Can you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get wi-fi connection to the guest with vbox the only option is using the NAT because there is no 'physical' adapter by default on the guest.
I suggest that you connect and ethernet cable to one of the ports of the host and change the network adapter to LAN and set it as a bridge adapter to that port to see if the adapters are working as it should be.

Comment: There is no option to connect an ethernet at my workplace

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution here would be to :-

Set the host into Bridged adapter mode then either, set the guest, to ensure DHCP is enabled, OR set the IP on the guest to be within the range of the host's network.

This shuold allow the guest to access the internet.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I tried, but not working.

Comment: Are you using DHCP or are you setting the IP manually?

Comment: I am using DHCP. I created bridge connection with Host-only adapter on host machine

Comment: OK, can you do another ifconfig?

Comment: Are you able to ping the host? 

Can you get the gateway and DNS addresses for the guest (http://iihelp.iinet.net.au/sites/iihelp.iinet.net.au/files/macgateway2.png) and also the DNS address from the host?

Comment: For the host and the guest DNS address is same 192.172.0.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60882/discussion-between-steven-davison-and-mansuu).